# The entries in a table do not wrap in a table's cell

Tags: tables

I have the following code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}

    \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

    %\newcolumntype{s}{>{\columncolor[HTML]{AAACED}} p{2.5cm}}
    \arrayrulecolor[HTML]{000000}
    \usepackage{geometry}
     \geometry{
     a4paper,
     total={170mm,257mm},
     left=20mm,
     top=20mm,
     }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{2cm}|p{3cm} |p{2.5cm} |p{4.5cm} |  }
    \hline
    \rowcolor{cyan} \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Interesting Factors} \\
    \hline
    Factor & Table & Description & Justification \\
    \hline
    FF\_FFFFFF & FF\_FFFFF\_V2 & ? &  \\ \hline
    \rowcolor{gray}
    FF\_FF\_FFFF & FF\_FFFFF\_V2 & Company's name & Base \\ \hline

    FF\_DDDD\_DDDD\_DDDDDDD & FF\_FFFFF\_V2 & Business Description & \cellcolor[HTML]{AA0044} Base    \\ \hline
    Angola && AO & AGO \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And for some reason the entry before the very last one, in the first column, does not wrap in a table cell... Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why? Because LaTeX has no rules to break this kind of ‘words’. You can use the `seqsplit` package and the eponymous command to allow breaking it at any point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{seqsplit} \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

%\newcolumntype{s}{>{\columncolor[HTML]{AAACED}} p{2.5cm}}
\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{000000}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
a4paper,
total={170mm,257mm},
left=20mm,
top=20mm,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ |p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{4.5cm}|}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{cyan} \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Interesting Factors} \\
  \hline
  Factor & Table & Description & Justification \\
  \hline
  FF\_FFFFFF & FF\_FFFFF\_V2 & ? & \\ \hline
  \rowcolor{gray}
  FF\_FF\_FFFF & FF\_FFFFF\_V2 & Company's name & Base \\ \hline
  \seqsplit{FF\_DDDD\_DDDD\_DDDDDDD} & FF\_FFFFF\_V2 & Business Description & \cellcolor[HTML]{AA0044} Base \\ \hline
  Angola & & AO & AGO \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]